# Statistical significance problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I've got an algorithm which assigns a score to a list of individuals (nodes). I want to discover which nodes received a statistically significant score. So I "randomized" the algorithm in order to obtain 100 random rankings of the same individuals. Now I've got my 100 rankings (Original + 100 Random). How can I check which nodes obtained a statistically significant score comparing the original with the random ones? Which statistical test could fit with my situation?

EDIT:

What is I define my null hypothesis as: "the observed value (original score) of node X appeared by chance". Then if the score of my original node X is higher than the 99 random scores, can I say that I reject the null hypothesis with a p-value < 0.01?

Comment: By "randomized" do you mean that you simulated scores? If that's the case, and it is not excessively expensive to simulate, you could run a larger simulation (e.g., $n \geq 10^3$, but this is arbitrary) and use the results to estimate the underlying distribution. Once you have an idea of the distribution, you could then produce a formal test.

Comment: Is the original score generated *only* by the algorithm? If so, is the algorithm deterministic or stochastic? It's not clear to me that statistical hypothesis testing makes any sense here. Couldn't you just analyze the algorithm & figure out if it allocates higher scores to some nodes than others?

Comment: The algorithm is stochastic. It's a classification problem so the randomization is: assign the class label randomly and the apply the algorithm. The distribution of the "random" scores is not normal. I just tested it.

Comment: Please note that you are not evaluating one null hypothesis: you are evaluating 100 interrelated hypotheses, one for each score.  You will never find any of them to be "statistically significant" because there are too many of them.  Could you possibly be trying to [detect outliers?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=outlier)